# UITableViewController not displaying

Tags: uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Is there a way to add the tableView portion of a UITableViewController to a UIView?

Here is what I've got...

1) **UIViewController - MainViewController**

2) **UIView - customUIView** - Added to MainViewController (This UIView is replaced when a new page is loaded)

- When a button is clicked all of the other pages in my app are loaded using (example)

  mainViewController.customUIView = [[LoginPage alloc] initWithFrame:mainViewController.view.bounds];

3) **UITableViewController - ScoresNotificationsPage** - Here is my issue, trying to add the tableView portion of this into the UIView and have it display on the MainViewController, just as if any other UIView was added.

- When I try loading the tableView portion of the UITableViewController into customUIView using:

  mainViewController.customUIView = [[ScoresNotificationsPage alloc] initWithFrame:mainViewController.view.bounds];

I get the following error

Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIView *' from 'ScoresNotificationsPage *'

Any idea of what I could do to get the tableView to show up?

Thank you in advance.

Whew...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `ScoresNotificationsPage` a child view controller and then simply add it: `[self.view addSubview:scoresPage.tableView]`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Since I'm not using storyboards, I had to check to see if a cell was nil and if so set a style and re-use identifier. Here's the code that I also used static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        
    }